# Unresolved reference: textField

Tags: kotlin, material-design

I get this message "Unresolved reference: textField" on the start of the third line on this block of code:

```
val items = listOf("Material", "Design", "Components", "Android")
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.list_item, items)
(textField.editText as? AutoCompleteTextView)?.setAdapter(adapter)
```

I just copied and pasted the code directly from the material design [documentation site](https://material.io/components/menus/android#exposed-dropdown-menus) following their instructions, but I doesn't seems to work. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there a variable called `textField` in scope?

Comment: @Egor No, there isn't, and it isn't on the the material design documentation

Answer (score 0):

In this case, textField is the @+id binded from your component *TextInputLayout*

Something like this.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout    
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
android:id="@+id/text_field"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```